# Intercept all nginx requests to serve series of static content?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

**Question:** Is there a way to 'intercept' more specific locations? Before many locations (e.g., location /activity, location = /search, location ~ "^/content/([a-f\d]{24})/$", etc.), I would like to do potentially serve html and then handle the original request.

**Background:** An nginx.conf I'm working with serves up a series of html pages (e.g., international agreement page, location page, supplier welcome page, etc.) following user SSO login and the user attempting to access a URL of our product.

The current nginx configuration works by adding a *try_files $uri /<location that could serve .html page>?redirecturi=$redirecturi;* to **many** location blocks. This is cumbersome because numerous locations point to the same location (e.g., /landing as seen below); it would be more maintainable to have a single location as an entry point to this 'flow' of html pages.

*Example location block that refers to a location (e.g., /landing) that can server html*

```
location /workitem {
    ...
    auth_request /auth;
    ...
    recursive_error_pages on;
    try_files $uri /landing?redirecturi=$redirecturi;
}
```

*Example location that can serve html*

```
location = /landing {
    internal;
    ...
    proxy_method GET;
    proxy_pass <scheme>://<host>/api/internationalAgreement?redirecturi=$redirecturi;
    recursive_error_pages on;             
    error_page 378 =200 /internationalAgreement.html;
    error_page 395 =200 /supplier?redirecturi=$redirecturi;
}
```

On the backend, we expose APIs to that update the user's session when they've seen a page:

```
router.get('/internationalAgreement',
 (req, res) => {
    const redirectUri = req.query.redirecturi;
    if (!redirectUri) {
      return res.status(403).end();
    }

    // International Agreement not posted yet
    if (req.session.showContentLandingPage === 'true') {
      return res.status(378).end();
    }
    ...
  });
```

Pending response code, the location block either serves the .html page or routes to a different block that might serve html (e.g., /supplier as referenced above in /landing). When the user clicks 'Next' on the html page, an HTTP request is made, the backend updates the user's session with the page they saw, then the request if 'forwarded' to another block that could serve html.

*Example location arrived when user clicks next*

```
location = /api/ge/itc {
    limit_except POST { deny all; }
    ...
    proxy_pass <scheme>://<host>/api/internationalAgreement?redirecturi=$arg_ouri;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 379 =200 /userLocation?redirecturi=$upstream_http_x_mbe_redirect;
}
```

Eventually, these locations just pass through requests after the users has stepped through the required pages.

I've tried searching for examples of locations that match all locations but generally can only find the '/' would match as a catch all and not intercept more specific locations.